# Split comma separated string into rows simplification

Tags: sql, sql-server

Note that this is for SQL Server 2014 so various built in functions are unavailable, and I don't have permission to create functions.

My data looks like this:

```
advisor_rep_id  individual_url_rep_codes    split_url_rep_codes
57444           9289                        9569
4407            397                         7128, 9226
52779           8613, 8614, 8616            (null)
56732           (null)                      9193, 4423
56713           3456                        9193, 4423
```

I am trying to convert every variation of `individual_url_rep_codes` and `split_url rep_codes` into one column (many rows) `urls`. Note that there can be more than 5 instances of both `individual_url_rep_codes` and `split_url rep_codes` per `advisor_rep_id`.

Expected output:

```
advisor_rep_id  urls
57444           9289  
57444           9569
4407            397
4407            7128
4407            9226
52779           8613
52779           8614
52779           8616
56732           9193
56732           4423
56713           3456
56713           9193
56713           4423
```

In my attempt below I am taking the first variable in `individual_url_rep_codes` then `union` with the second variable in `individual_url_rep_codes` then `union` with the first variable in `split_url_rep_codes` then `union` with the second variable in `split_url_rep_codes` and I would continue unioning to cover for all comma separated variables in the string.

There has to be another way! Any ideas?
FYI, I know I get a bunch of nulls in the output which will require a subquery to get rid off.

```
with cte as (
    SELECT advisor_rep_id, 
CONVERT(XML,'<Emails><email>'  + REPLACE(individual_url_rep_codes,', ', '</email><email>') + '</email></Emails>') AS individual_urls,
CONVERT(XML,'<Emails><email>'  + REPLACE(split_url_rep_codes,', ', '</email><email>') + '</email></Emails>') AS split_urls
    from table
            )

SELECT advisor_rep_id,
CASE PATINDEX('%[ ;' + CHAR(10) + ']%', LTRIM(individual_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)')))
WHEN 0 THEN LTRIM(individual_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)'))
ELSE SUBSTRING(LTRIM(individual_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)')), 1, PATINDEX('%[ ;' + CHAR(10) + ']%',LTRIM(individual_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)'))) - 1) end as urls
from cte
where individual_urls is not null

union all

SELECT advisor_rep_id,
CASE PATINDEX('%[ ;' + CHAR(10) + ']%', LTRIM(individual_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[2]','varchar(100)')))
WHEN 0 THEN LTRIM(individual_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[2]','varchar(100)'))
ELSE SUBSTRING(LTRIM(individual_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[2]','varchar(100)')), 1, PATINDEX('%[ ;' + CHAR(10) + ']%',LTRIM(individual_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[2]','varchar(100)'))) - 1) end as urls
from cte
where individual_urls is not null

union all

SELECT advisor_rep_id,
CASE PATINDEX('%[ ;' + CHAR(10) + ']%', LTRIM(split_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)')))
WHEN 0 THEN LTRIM(split_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)'))
ELSE SUBSTRING(LTRIM(split_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)')), 1, PATINDEX('%[ ;' + CHAR(10) + ']%',LTRIM(split_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[1]','varchar(100)'))) - 1) end as url
from cte
where split_urls is not null

union all

SELECT advisor_rep_id,
CASE PATINDEX('%[ ;' + CHAR(10) + ']%', LTRIM(split_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[2]','varchar(100)')))
WHEN 0 THEN LTRIM(split_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[2]','varchar(100)'))
ELSE SUBSTRING(LTRIM(split_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[2]','varchar(100)')), 1, PATINDEX('%[ ;' + CHAR(10) + ']%',LTRIM(split_urls.value('/Emails[1]/email[2]','varchar(100)'))) - 1) end as url
from cte
where split_urls is not null
```

Comment: Tough luck... Don't store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: @jarlh the fact that I cant create functions should tell that I am not the DBA.. Stuck in a bad situation and reaching out for a potential solution

Comment: Storing multiple values as a comma-separated list is a serious problem, no matter the database. Use *separate* tables. You gain nothing by stuffing multiple IDs in the same field - you can't read them afterwards, you can't use them to join with other tables, you can't *index* them which results in very bad performance

Comment: Then ask your DBA how they would unravel the nightmare they created for you to deal with. I understand you didn't create this but you have to deal with it. What are you expecting as output from your sample?

Comment: @user8834780 whether you are a DBA or not doesn't have anything to do with the schema problems. If those values are IDs, use different tables. If they are just a bunch of codes **with no other role as data**, use an **xml-typed** column instead of a CSV string. XML can be parsed and queried since 2005. The fastest splitting technique actually converts the string into XML before querying individual elements.

Comment: @SeanLange added expected output

Comment: Tell your DBA/boss, he has two choices:   give you permission to create functions, or have a solution with terrible performance that will be a maintenance nightmare in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple XML Parse with a little twist...  We just concatenate the two rep_code columns.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([advisor_rep_id] varchar(50),[individual_url_rep_codes] varchar(50),[split_url_rep_codes] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (57444,'9289','9569')
,(4407,'397','7128, 9226')
,(52779,'8613, 8614, 8616',NULL)
,(56732,NULL,'9193, 4423')
,(56713,'3456','9193, 4423')

Select A.[advisor_rep_id]
      ,URLS = B.RetVal
 from @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(concat([individual_url_rep_codes],',',[split_url_rep_codes]),',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
 Where B.RetVal is not null
```

**Returns**

```
advisor_rep_id  URLS 
57444           9289
57444           9569
4407            397
4407            7128
4407            9226
52779           8613
52779           8614
52779           8616
56732           9193
56732           4423
56713           3456
56713           9193
56713           4423
```

Comment: I will try this out, than you so much!

Comment: @user8834780 Happy to help.  Just a note: the Where is optional.  Remove if you want to see the NULLs

Comment: Well done as always John. I was going to post my version of using this technique but thankfully saw yours first. Much cleaner than what I was coming up with.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic